# How to create a save method in an abstract model that checks whether an instance exists?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have the following models:

```
class PlaceMixin(models.Model):    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    sublocality = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Bar(PlaceMixin):
   pass

class Restaurant(PlaceMixin):
   pass
```

Bar and Restaurant have almost same save() method:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        bar = Bar.objects.get(address=self.address)

    except Bar.DoesNotExist:
         Do something
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        restaurant = Restaurant.objects.get(address=self.address)

    except Restaurant.DoesNotExist:
         Do something
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I was wondering if I can put the method in the Abstract model and pass it to the two inherited model?

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        temp = self.objects.get(address=self.address)

    except self.DoesNotExist:
         Do something
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Something like this? But you can query in an abstract model. I basically need to check if an instance exists for executing an action.

Comment: I do not see `id_google` declared as an attribute of any model.  Also what is that you want to accomplish in the `expect` blocks where you have `Do something`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `abstract` metadata to achieve this. And if you want to use any variable inside class model, you just need to use `self.__class__` like so:

```py
class PlaceMixin(models.Model):    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    sublocality = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            self.__class__.objects.get(address=self.address)
        except self.__class__.DoesNotExist:
            # Do something
        else:
            super().save(*args, **kwargs)


class Bar(PlaceMixin):
   pass

class Restaurant(PlaceMixin):
   pass
```

There are a lot of code design like this in Django source code, a lot of good practices in their project so give it a try. E.g: [a line of code on Django repo](https://github.com/django/django/blob/3ca9df51c779510fbbfe296ca95a127d1dec2f87/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L366)

Comment: Sorry that's not the question. The question is how to put the save() in the abstract model.

Comment: Qouc Ho  No that's not the solution. The question is how to implement the try and except functionality in an abstract model.

Comment: Updated. Followed this point `I basically need to check if an instance exists for executing an action.`

Answer (score 0):

You can make a common save method for both `Restaurant` and `Bar` model in a Mixin class like this:

```
from django.apps import apps

class CommonMixin(object):
     def save(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        if self.__class__.__name__ == "Resturant":
             model = apps.get_model('app_name', 'Bar')    
             if model.objects.filter(address=self.address).exists():
                     ...
        else:
            model = apps.get_model('app_name', 'Restaurant')    
             if model.objects.filter(address=self.address).exists():
                     ...
        super(CommonMixin, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

And import it in both `Restaurant` and `Bar` class:

```
 class Restaurant(CommonMixin, PlaceMixin):
     ...

 class Bar(CommonMixin, PlaceMixin):
     ...
```

---

Probably a better approach is to use a separate model for Address information. Then you won't need a new Mixin to override save(the approach given above feels like over engineering). So lets say you have a different address model, there you can simply put `unique=True` to restrict duplicate entries:

```
class Address(models.Model):
     address = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)


class PlaceMixin(models.Model):
     address = models.ForeignKey(Address)
     ...
```